# [Android]Keyboard and KeyboardListener

Tags: java, android, oop, keyboard

I'm currently programming my first android program: a "SmartSMS" for school. I aim at giving the opportunity to an user to write a SMS with a numeric keyboard. He just has to key in the digits corresponding with the word he wants to write and he will get suggests to write the word.

I was said that the best way is to create a keyboard. There are so many thing I didn't understand! For example, when I work with Android documentation, they want me to add this:

```
    @Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    MyKeyboardView inputView =
        (MyKeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate( R.layout.input, null);

    inputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
inputView.setKeyboard(mLatinKeyboard);
    return mInputView;
}
```

I don't understand what is exactly a `Keyboard` and a `KeyboardActionListener`. 
Why the parameter of `setOnKeyboardActionListener` is `this` (an `MyKeboardView`) and not a `KeyboardActionListener`? And where does `mLatinKeyboard` comes from?

When I try to instance a `KeyboardActionListener`, they say to me that the method is abstract and I when I try to derive the class or to write `implements KeyboardActionListener` in the main class, they ask me to declare again all the methods.

And concerning the `Keyboard`, I thought that the layout xml file where I drew my own keyboard was the "input" (in `R.layout.input`). Why do I need an other xml file represented by the `Keyboard`?

Thank you for your help. I am getting more and more lost in this Android universe.

PS : I am french, so if you are, it maybe would be easier for both of us to answer in french.

Answer (score 0):

If you're providing suggestions in the SMS app then you could just set your text field type to be numbers. Check [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html)
And all of the keyboards should pop up in the numpad layout

Making a keyboard is very complicated, I don't think you should try to make a keyboard for your school project